# How can I center an element inside a tile in Bulma framework

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am using the Bulma framework for my webpage's css. I am using the tiles feature to design my page. I cannot seem to find how to center an element inside a tile.

I have written a 'center' class in the bulma.css file as below :

```
.center{
  left : 40%;
  right : 20%;
}
```

This does seem to work for an image I am importing :

```
 <div class="tile is-ancestor">
  <div class="tile is-parent">
    <div class="tile is-child ">
      <figure class="image is-64x64 center">
        <img src="/static/img/my_image.png" alt="" >
      </figure>

<!---more code---->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the same doesn't work for a form just below the image(still inside the tile :

```
<form class="center" action="{{url_for('displayGraph')}}" method="post">

    <input class="center" style="width:80%;font-size:12pt;" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="How can I help you?">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ask away!">
    </div>

  </form>
```

Not sure what to do about this. Can someone please help me?

Comment: what are you trying to do? center the form elements?

Comment: Yes, right now the input field and the submit button are left aligned.  I want the text field to be centered and the submit button below to be near the center of the text field.

Answer (score 5):

Use **`has-text-centered`** class in Bulma for centering the text inside an element.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="has-text-centered" action="{{url_for('displayGraph')}}" method="post">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input style="width:80%;font-size:12pt;" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="How can I help you?">
  <br>
  <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ask away!">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! It does take care of the submit button now. The text input field however stretches from the leftmost extreme to the right most. Is there anyway I can limit the size of the text field while keeping it center aligned?

Comment: use `style="width:50%;"` to set the width of the input filed manually.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think a little modification in your .center class may help.

```
.center{
  margin : 0 auto;
  text-align : center;
}
```